# HTTP POST request isn't being sent from NextJS client to Go server after deployment, but it worked during development

Tags: typescript, next.js, http-post

It is fullstack web application with NextJS and Go server. Due to restriction with NextJS, I had to first make the api call to NextJS serverless function. Then, from that serverless function sends the http post request to Go backend.

Everything was working perfectly fine in development. But after deployment, all "POST", "PUT" and "DELETE" methods were not sent to the server even though "GET" request worked. The client was able to fetch the data.

I'm assuming the server is working fine. It's working as expected during development and even after deployment, the http requests worked fine with POST MAN.

*The interesting thing is after deployment the POST, PUT and DELETE requests were never sent to the server, except the GET requests*

*I have also setup CORS in Go server*

#### The Client code calling the `api/clinic`

```
    async function handleAdd(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            console.log("adding", clinic)
            const res = await axios.post('/api/clinic', clinic, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                withCredentials: true
            })
            const data = await res.data
            console.log("successfully add clinic", data)
            // window.location.reload()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
```

#### The API function send http request to GO server

```
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/admin/create-clinic`, clinic, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                withCredentials: true
            })
            const data = await response.data
            return res.end(JSON.stringify(data))
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.end(JSON.stringify({"error": err.message }))
        }
    }
```

#### The error shown in vercel terminal

*I don't understand why the request header is set to GET even though in the code I made sure it is POST request*

```
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 405,
    statusText: 'Method Not Allowed',
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      date: 'Mon, 03 Apr 2023 06:20:36 GMT',
      'content-length': '0',
      server: 'railway',
      connection: 'close'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Array],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [AxiosHeaders],
      withCredentials: true,
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://.../admin/create-clinic',
      data: '{"id":0,"name":"CNA 3","location":"Pyin Oo Lwin Main Road"}'
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /admin/create-clinic HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.3.4\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: host\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/admin/create-clinic',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'host',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: ''
  }
}
```

I was expecting a JSON object in the response upon successful http request. But the request was never sent to the server.

Comment: It's all good now, the code is just fine, the url had an extra "/" which i didn't see it (even after 3 days) till i posted here.